# 'do' keyword in C

Tags: c, keyword

`do` is a keyword in C and all I have seen is that it is only used with `while`. So my question is can `do` be used alone without `while`.

If yes how?

Comment: From the spec: ['do' statement 'while' '(' expression ')' ';'](http://eli-project.sourceforge.net/c_html/c.html#s6.6)

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? If what you need is to scope some variable declaration, the a simple { } block will do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No. It cannot.

To be more precise, this is what the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards.html#9899) has to say:

> ### 6.8.5 Iteration statements
>
> #### Syntax
>
> iteration-statement:
>
> > `while ( expression ) statement`
> > `do statement while ( expression ) ;`
> > `for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement`
> > `for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement`

Comment: Note for readers: If it looks like there is a semicolon missing between `declaration` and `expressionopt`, that is because the semicolon is actually part of `declaration`.

Answer (score -1):

do is a keyword which is used in the do-while loop.
General syntax of using the do-while loop is:
do{//Logic
}while(condition);

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score -2):

As an aside, the do statement is most often used to provide some syntactic sugar and use preprocessor macros as normal C functions:

```
#define MY_MACRO_FNC(x) do { whatever(x); } while(0)
/* later in you call this macros as */
MY_MACRO_FNC(x);
```

Comment: Why would you need the loop in that macro?

Comment: so you can add the semicolon. Instead of having one function call, imagine you have several lines which have to go in curly braces